# My NSLog inside drawInContext never stops

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm curious what happens when I animate layers with `CABasicAnimation`, so I put an `NSLog` in  the layer's `- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx`. But the behaviour is rather strange, it goes through all the values and then continues on logging with the final one or very close to it.

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
animation.duration = 5.0;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.delegate = self;
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:255];
animation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
```

This produces an the following with an `NSLog` logging the animating value.

```
...
value: 14
value: 13
value: 12
value: 11
value: 10
value: 9
value: 8
value: 7
value: 7
value: 6
value: 5
value: 4
value: 3
value: 3
value: 2
value: 1
value: 0
value: 0
value: 0
value: 0
...
```

And it never stop, it keeps on logging `0`. Why does it do that? Does that mean that this method is called that many times when the `NSLog` is not there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well your animation.removedOnCompletion is no

ALSO
somebody has to draw your layer so it is to be expected sometimes

Comment: How would you advise me to achieve the same result without that property set to no? I do want the state to stay after the animation is complete.

Comment: But why does it keep on "drawing" if the animation has reached it's target result?